# xstl transform inserts namespace in result elements (revisited)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have an xml file where I need to rename elements.   (also later to transform elements to attributes).   The xslt transform inserts the default namespace into all the top level elements.   I don't want that.   I have seen quite a number of questions about this problem but still having issues with the desired result and understanding why...

1. The best I can do with exclude-result-prefixes is:

```
<ar xmlns="">
<dyu xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net">ábada</dyu>
```

Why is the namespace removed from only ar?  And why does it preserve the xmlns=""?

2. If i **remove** the renaming portion of the transform so it basically just copies the original file:

```
      <xsl:template match="/c:lexique/c:headword">                                                                                                     
      <ar>                                                                                                                                           
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>                                                                                                  
      </ar>                                                                                                                                          
      </xsl:template>
```

then 'exclude-result-prefixes' seems to have no effect at all.  Whether its there or not there is no namespace inserted.  Why?

Is there a hitch with xslt3?   I need to use this as it handles the latin extended characters and sorting correctly.

The xml is as follows:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>                                                                                                             
<lexique xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net"                                                                                                       
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                                                     
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.coastsystems.net headwords2.xsd"                                                                           
>                                                                                                                                                  
  <headword>                                                                                                                                       
    <dyu>ábada</dyu>                                                                                                                               
    <alt>abada</alt>                                                                                                                               
    <emp></emp>                                                                                                                                    
    <cf>fewu</cf>                                                                                                                                  
    <trans>                                                                                                                                        
      <lang>fr</lang>                                                                                                                              
      <detail></detail>                                                                                                                            
      <speech>                                                                                                                                     
        <type></type>                                                                                                                              
        <t-uuid>7b8612bc-23c7-4241-817f-f6fcd9bff8ac</t-uuid>                                                                                      
        <def>                                                                                                                                      
          <gloss>jamais</gloss>                                                                                                                    
          <gl-id>bbc05aae-8f08-4ab7-91ae-3b52533a896f</gl-id>                                                                                      
          <note2></note2>                                                                                                                          
          <note3></note3>                                                                                                                          
          <note4></note4>                                                                                                                          
          <tags></tags>                                                                                                                            
          <example>                                                                                                                                
            <source>a tɛ koɲuman kɛ abada.</source>                                                                                                
            <target>Il ne fait jamais quelque chose de bien.</target>                                                                              
            <ex-id>2c592b68-0d29-4b6c-8614-005adab4fba5</ex-id>                                                                                    
          </example>                                                                                                                               
        </def>                                                                                                                                     
      </speech>                                                                                                                                    
    </trans>                                                                                                                                       
  </headword>                                                                                                                                      
</lexique>
```

With the xslt stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                              
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"                                                                                                                      
  xmlns:xsl  = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                                                                                              
  xmlns:c="http://www.coastsystems.net"                                                                                                            
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl c"                                                                                                                  
>                                                                                                                                                  
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                   
 <xsl:template match="/">                                                                                                                          
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>                                                                                                      
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                   
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">                                                                                                                 
    <xsl:copy>                                                                                                                                     
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>                                                                                                    
    </xsl:copy>                                                                                                                                    
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                   
  <xsl:template match="/c:lexique/c:headword">                                                                                                     
    <ar>                                                                                                                                           
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>                                                                                                  
    </ar>                                                                                                                                          
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(`xslt3 -xsl:rename.xsl -s:headwords.xml)` Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lexique xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.coastsystems.net headwords2.xsd">
   <ar xmlns="">
      <dyu xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net">ábada</dyu>
      <alt xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net">abada</alt>
      <emp xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net"/>
      <cf xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net">fewu</cf>
      <trans xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net">
         <lang>fr</lang>
         <detail/>
         <speech>
            <type/>
            <t-uuid>7b8612bc-23c7-4241-817f-f6fcd9bff8ac</t-uuid>
            <def>
               <gloss>jamais</gloss>
               <gl-id>bbc05aae-8f08-4ab7-91ae-3b52533a896f</gl-id>
               <note2/>
               <note3/>
               <note4/>
               <tags/>
               <example>
                  <source>a tɛ koɲuman kɛ abada.</source>
                  <target>Il ne fait jamais quelque chose de bien.</target>
                  <ex-id>2c592b68-0d29-4b6c-8614-005adab4fba5</ex-id>
               </example>
            </def>
         </speech>
      </trans>
   </ar>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lexique xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.coastsystems.net headwords2.xsd">
   <ar>
      <dyu>ábada</dyu>
      <alt>abada</alt>
      <emp/>
      <cf>fewu</cf>
      <trans>
         <lang>fr</lang>
         <detail/>
=====  snipped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction to `exclude-result-prefixes` only excludes them if they aren't used. If you want those other elements to be produced without a namespace, then you need to create elements without a namespace(using the `local-name()`), instead of using `xsl:copy`.

You can achieve this by adding a generic template for any element (following the identity template that is matching `@*|node()` so that it has a higher priority match.

If you want all of the elements bound to the `` namespace, but not with a prefix, then set the default namespace in the stylesheet `xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"                                                                                                                      
    xmlns:xsl  = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     
    xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net"    
    xmlns:c="http://www.coastsystems.net"                                                                                                            
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl c"                                                                                                                  
    >                                                                                                                                                  
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />                                                                                         

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">                                                                                                                 
        <xsl:copy>                                                                                                                                     
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>                                                                                                    
        </xsl:copy>                                                                                                                                    
    </xsl:template>  
    
    <xsl:template match="*">                                                                                                                 
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">                                                                                                                                     
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>                                                                                                    
        </xsl:element>                                                                                                                                    
    </xsl:template> 
    
    <xsl:template match="/c:lexique/c:headword">                                                                                                     
        <ar>                                                                                                                                           
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>                                                                                                  
        </ar>                                                                                                                                          
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                  
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also change the match expression for the identity template to list the specific `node()` and not include `*`:  `@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()`.

Comment: Thanks Mads.   That did solve the issue.  But I didn't have to match local-name.   As soon as I put the     xmlns="http://www.coastsystems.net"    in the header it no longer inserts namespace.